# how to use variable in jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

**what is happening**

i have ansible jinja2 template with following code

```
nodes:
{% for host in abc_masters %}
- address: "{{ abc_ip_address }}"
  port: "22"
  role:
    - controlplane
    - etcd
  hostname_override: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  user: {{ admin_user }}
  docker_socket: /var/run/docker.sock
  ssh_key_path: {{ ssh_key_path }}
  labels: {}
{% endfor %}
```

**what is the issue**

when i am running the ansible-playbook command , getting following errors.

> fatal: [abc-worker-3]: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'abc_masters' is undefined" }

now, not getting where to define "abc_masters" variable ?? 
further, in the hosts file of inventory folder , abc_masters is mentioned already ...

```
[abc_masters]
abc-master-0 ansible_ssh_user=administrator  ansible_host=192.168.160.101 ansible_port=22 abc_ip_address=192.168.160.101
abc-master-1 ansible_ssh_user=administrator  ansible_host=192.168.160.102 ansible_port=22 abc_ip_address=192.168.160.102
```

**what is expected**

my understanding is  , jinja2 template should take this variable from hosts file and iterate over the array to get each host details ... is it correct ?

please suggest where i m missing . Do i need to define this variable somewhere else ? what is that location then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`abc_masters`* is name of the group. Use special variable *`groups`* to iterate the hosts in this group

```
{% for host in groups['abc_masters'] %}
```

Quoting from [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)

> groups: A dictionary/map with all the groups in inventory and each group has the list of hosts that belong to it